# Visual Studio is broken (new installation)," cmd not found"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I try to run a Python program , the following error outputs :

> G:\OneDrive\ [...] ,RedirectOutput "g:\OneDrive\VS Code Projekte\Python Projekte\Tasks__init__.py" "
>   Der Befehl "cmd" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
>   konnte nicht gefunden werden.

it translates to : ' The command "cmd" is either misspelled or
could not be found.'

I tried to install vs code on a new PC, and I reinstalled python a few times, manually set the PATH and other things. So far nothing worked. On my other pc I used VSC for a few weeks already, and everything worked fine. I hope someone can help and it's an easy fix. //edit: The python program should just print hello world

Comment: "manually set the PATH" is the way to get into this kind of trouble.  A rogue installer also tends to do this kind of damage.  c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe should always be found through the PATH.  Ensure that c:\windows and c:\windows\system32 are still included.

Comment: I have both folders in the Path, and didnt change anything there beforehand.

Comment: If you press Windows+R, type in "cmd" and press enter, does that open a command prompt? Does c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe exist?

Comment: honestly I just wanna program some stuff and why does it always need to be so hard with my main pc

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check the presence of `cmd.exe`?

```
<Prompt> where cmd
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

When you find the `cmd.exe` parent directory, put it in the `PATH` environment variable (the system one or the user one?).